# Masterpage Help

Tags: custom-masterpage, branding, troubleshooting

I have been trying to change/update the masterpage, I have some requirements to rebrand our front page.  I have saved a copy in SP Designer, Seattlecopy2.html, edited the script there, clicked save and refresh but when I click preview in browser the changes do not show up.

I mean even basic changes like changing the ribbonrow color. I'm testing on SP 2013 using SharePoint Designer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the Masterpage on the site to point to Seattlecopy2?

Comment: I did.  The changes still would not show up

Comment: OK. Did you publish a main version (1.0) on the HTML file, and did you get the corresponding .master file as well?

Comment: I did, and I have the .master file to go along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the master page to the system pages and aite pages to see the changes in your SharePoint site.
Make sure you have the publishing features enabled and then go to site settings ->Master Page under look and feel. Select your new master on both options

Comment: I have had all of those features enabled and have done that...still nothing

Comment: On SharePoint designer click on the masterpage and set it as system and page master.